# Single Server, Multiple Clients UDP Application in C (Winsock)

Tags: winapi, udp, winsock

I have created single Server and Single Client echo application. It works fine for single server and single client. But now I want to make it more practical by handling multiple clients for a single Server. I came accross the idea of using listen() function at Server side to handle multiple client connections but then I came to know that listen is only used for TCP. Kindly help me with this. below is my functional code for single Server and Single Client. Help me with how can I modify it to make a Single Server Multiple Client application.

**SERVER:**

```
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

int main()
{

SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in serverSocket, clientSocket;

char receiveBuffer[1000];
//int receiveBufferLength=1000;
int clientSocketLength;
int recv_len;

clientSocketLength = sizeof(clientSocket) ;

WSADATA wsa; 
//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
  printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Socket Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}
printf("Socket created.\n");   

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
serverSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverSocket.sin_port = htons( PORT );

//Bind
if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&serverSocket , sizeof(serverSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\nBind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Bind done\n\n");

//keep listening for data

while(1)
{
    printf("\n\t\t\tWaiting for data...\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    //receiveBuffer[2000]=NULL;

    if((recv_len = recvfrom(s, receiveBuffer, 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\n\nrecvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while(1);
    }

    //print details of the client/peer and the data received
    printf("\n\nReceived packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(clientSocket.sin_addr), ntohs(clientSocket.sin_port));
    printf("\nClient Says: " );
        printf(receiveBuffer,recv_len);



    //now reply the client with the same data
    if (sendto(s, receiveBuffer, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &clientSocket, clientSocketLength) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nsendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
       // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while(1);
    }
    else
        printf("\nMessage Sent Back to Client");

}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;

}
```

**CLIENT:**

```
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
#define SERVER "10.0.1.25"  //ip address of udp server
//#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

int main(void)
{
struct sockaddr_in connectedSocket;

int s;
int length=sizeof(connectedSocket);

char receiveBuffer[1000];
char message[1000];

//clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
memset(receiveBuffer,'\0', 1000);

WSADATA wsa;
//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...\n");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("\nFailed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("\n.........Initialised.\n");


//create socket
if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\n\nsocket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


//setup address structure
memset((char *) &connectedSocket, 0, sizeof(connectedSocket));
connectedSocket.sin_family = AF_INET;
connectedSocket.sin_port = htons(PORT);
 //connectedSocket.sin_port = INADDR_BROADCAST;
connectedSocket.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);

while(1)
{
    printf("\n\n\nEnter message : ");
    gets(message);

  //send the message
    if (sendto(s, message,sizeof(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket, sizeof(connectedSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\nsendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        printf("\nMessage Successfully sent to Server");
      // fflush(stdout);

    if (recvfrom(s, receiveBuffer, 1000, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket,&length) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       printf("\nrecvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nServer Says : ");
    printf(receiveBuffer,sizeof(receiveBuffer));

}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Anybody who can help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain a few things for you that might be confusing.

First, in your server you need to set `serverSocket.sin_addr.s_addr` to `INADDR_ANY` even if you want to broadcast. You don't want to make it `INADDR_BROADCAST`. This is simply telling the server to bind on *any* IP address your computer has, cause a single computer can have more than 1 IP. Which you are doing correctly.

But how can you broadcast from the server? You need to use `setsockopt` with `SO_BROADCAST` parameter like this ...

```
int options = 1;
if ((setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST,(char *)&options,sizeof(options))) < 0){
    printf("%d",WSAGetLastError());
}
```

This will make your server *listens* for broadcasts, but how can you *send* broadcasts? You need to set `INADDR_BROADCAST` in the `s_addr` field in the **sockaddr** structure before calling `sendto` function.

```
clientSocket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
```

Then use `sendto` with `clientSocket` to boardcast your messsage back.

Second, in your client code, you have two options depending on your application.

1. If you want your clients to send message first to the server (direct without broadcast) then you are doing it right, by setting `inet_addr(SERVER)` so the client send the message to your server only.
2. But, if you want the client to broadcast the message, then you need to use `setsockopt` again in your client, same as in your server, and set the address in `connectSocket`structure to `INADDR_BROADCAST`.

Finally, it would be better if you tell us what are you trying to accomplish here. If you want clients to connect to server first, then the server *announce* the client to other clients, then you might take TCP instead of UDP.

Comment: Done Broadcasting by following your instructions, but I had to use bind() on clint side :|

Comment: You don't need bind to _send_ you need it only to _receive_. In the client, just set `INADDR_BROADCAST` in `s_addr` then set `SO_BROADCAST` in `setsockopt` then `sendto` with your socket structure.

Comment: Yes. bind is needed to receive. But, it seems that you are doing both (send and receive) in your clients. You want the clients to receive also, so that's why you need bind in the client too.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much @KarimElDeeb for all the support, means a lot :)

Comment: You already got almost everything about sockets in a very short time. You might also want to [read more](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/) about winsock, along with examples. It will help you understand what type of [strategy](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/io-strategies.html) to use, like [asynchronous sockets](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/multiplayer-and-network-programming/programming-with-asynchronous-sockets-r1297). This will help you make (an event-based) winsock GUI apps that send you windows messages when something (connect, send, receive, etc.) happens.

Comment: So nice of you for all the help :)

Comment: NOw the problem is that it works fine on same machine, but when I run my client on some different machine and try to bind() the client with Server's IP address running on some different machine, bind() fails :( how do I solve it @KarimElDeeb

Comment: Since I am trying to bind the Client at Server's IP Address and that address is not available at Client's machine, so that's why it gives error, i guess :(

Comment: Exactly. You can only bind to IP addresses on your machine. That's why you should set the IP to `INADDR_ANY` and let the operating system pick one for you. May I know why you want to bind to the server's IP?

Comment: Since Server is the SENDER in my case located on different machine, and I want to receive the data Broadcasted by Server at the Client side, so I want the Client to bind() to Server address, so that it picks data from Server's address only :( Am I doing wrong?

Comment: The client should bind with `INADDR_ANY`. That means, any IP address on the machine it is on. Just make sure it binds on the same port number. When the server broadcasts a message with `INADDR_BROADCAST` then _all_ clients binding will get it. To make it simple, if you want to send use `INADDR_BROADCAST`, and if you want to bind use `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: Ahhhhh finally, that worked on different machines :)
I have no words to thank you KarimElDeeb. You are a Genius :)

Comment: Sir! Now may I get a little more help from you regarding my [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403789/handling-10-clients-with-a-single-udp-server-using-winsock)