# Handling 10 Clients with a Single UDP Server using Winsock

Tags: multithreading, udp, winsock, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have already established a Server-Client Application using UDP Sockets, but my Server is not capable of handling more than one Client at a time. Now I want to modify my applicaton in such a way that there are 10 Clients each running on different machines and my Server running on a separate machine. I want my Server to be able to communicate with each of the 10 Clients running on 10 different machines. I also don't want to miss the data coming from any of the Client.
What is the best possible way to do it? Kindly share some examples with me:(
I have been searching it on internet since a week, but was unable to find anything that may suit my application requirements. 
Waiting for help.

Comment: The problem is that [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), by design, is not a reliable protocol. There is no guarantee of delivery or ordering. Data can, and will most likely, be lost unless you implement your own protection in your application. That's why there is [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and it seems it fits your application better than UDP.

Comment: But I am forced to use UDP :( not allowed to work on TCP :( What should I do now? I can try implementing protection in my application once it starts working with ten Clients at a time.

Comment: Trying to make UDP reliable is hard enough. UDP is connectionless, it just send a message an _hope_ it reach the server. The server might be offline, or non-existent and your `sendto` function will succeed, there is no way to tell. I'm afraid I can not help you with that, but I will try to give you a hint. First, send a message from the client to the server, then the server once gets the message should reply and and say i got it, so the client knows the message succeed, if the client didn't get it, it should re-send it again. TCP already handles that for you.

Comment: looks like it can help me :) I am gonna try it now :) and what about handling 10 Clients? Should I use Threads for this?

Comment: I don't think you need multi-threading for this. Your server is handling only 10 clients via UDP, so you are fine without threads.

Comment: And What if two Clients send data simultaneously? How many chances are there that the Server is going to miss some data?

Comment: Sure, that's UDP, and data loss should be expected. When the server miss something, the client who sent it will not get a message from the server saying _i got your message_ so the client will know the message wasn't received and should re-send it. The server should identify the clients with their IP:Port pair, to keep track on who sent what. When the client get a reply from the server say it got the message, then it should proceed to send the next message, etc.

Comment: You have always helped me with all my stupid questions. Thank you again :)